# How to use Yii variable in extjs

Tags: php, extjs, yii

I want to use the `Yii::app()` variable in `ExtJs` like below:

```
Ext.create('Ext.Toolbar',{
    region:'north',
    contentEl:'northPart',
    height:32,
    items:[
      {
        text:'<?php echo Yii::app()->name ?>',
        iconCls:'bmenu'
      }
    ]
});
```

But it is not working.
How to achieve that?

Comment: *"it is not working."* - How should anybody know what that means... Please explain what you expect and what happens instead.

Comment: r u sure thats not working ? It seems your items property starts with Uppercase

Answer (score 0):

what you are doing can be done if you put the string in an invisible DIV and then from ExtJS code, get the DIV html in a variable and use it in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Class-cfg-singleton to get global configuration from web pages to your js
for example 
put it on your php page

```
Ext.define('MyConf', {
    singleton: true,
    YiiAppName: '<?php echo Yii::app()->name ?>'
});
```

then you can use it like

```
Ext.create('Ext.Toolbar',{
    region:'north',
    contentEl:'northPart',
    height:32,
    items:[
      {
        text:MyConf.YiiAppName,
        iconCls:'bmenu'
      }
    ]
});
```

Comment: It cannot be used in alone js file, have to write js into php file, then done

Comment: @user1438980 yeah that's what i mean. so u can add singleton ext class to your main php page. then u can use it on alone js.